# printing the percent completed

Tags: java, double, long-integer

I am trying to divide 2 Long's in order to find the percentage. However, I only get `0.0%` or when they are equal, `100.0%`. This is what I am doing

```
long size =
long mem = 

double avg = (double)(size / mem) * 100;
```

Comment: Please do a search before you ask a question next time.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis And what search terms would you use? Assume that the OP is completely unaware of the term "integer division".

Comment: @Mysticial `java long division` so many results

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Fair enough since the OP did use the word "divide" in the question. But if the OP had no clue it had anything to do with division, it'd be a lot harder.

Answer (score 5):

You're doing `long` division which truncates the fractional part of the number. At least one of the operands is required to be a `double` to produce a non-zero `double`, You could do:

```
double avg = (double)size / mem * 100;
```

The numerator now becomes a `double` as a cast has [high precedence](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~palsetia/java/precedenceTable.html) than the division operator `/`.

Comment: Thanks this did the trick. I laughed at the `long` division play on words

Comment: This will work but you can get more decimal places than you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid long decimal numbers you can use.

```
long percentage = 100 * size / mem; // as an integer.
```

If you want one decimal place you can do

```
double percentage = (1000 * size / mem) / 10.0;
```

Comment: In the first case, it will round down the fraction. If you don't multiply by 100 first, you get 0% or 100% as suggested.  If you multiply by 100 first, it rounds down the percentage so you get 0, 1, 2 .. 99, 100.  if you multiply by 1000 and divide by 10.0 you get 0.0, 0.1, 0.2 ... 99.9, 100.0